# Are questions about the longevity of a particular make/model on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am considering purchasing a high mileage car and thought about asking if this particular make/model/year is generally known to last more than X miles.

Would that type of question be on topic here?

Answer (score 3):

This question would be off-topic on the site, because it is asking for shopping assistance. If you check the car out and see something which is not quite right, or you have a question about, as long as the question is specific about the running of the vehicle, it would be on-topic. If all else fails, you can always ask your shopping question over at [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop), which is the site's chatroom.

Comment: imagine a similar question that does not mention making a purchase. Here's a similar situation that someone else had 7 years ago. Same question, but nothing to do with purchasing a car: http://www.cadillacforums.com/forums/cadillac-cts-first-generation-forum-2003/203906-2003-cts-3-2-165k-life.html